# How to show that this statistic is complete

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, parameter-estimation

Suppose that $S, {f_θ : θ ∈ Θ})$ is a statistical model, corresponding to an observed random
vector $\mathbf X = (X_1, . . . , X_n).$

Let $\theta_1(\mathbf X)$ and $\theta_2(\mathbf X)$ be unbiased estimators for $\theta$ . Define $\theta_3(\mathbf X) = a \theta_1(\mathbf X) +(1-a)\theta_2(\mathbf X)$.

I have deduced that $\theta_3(\mathbf X)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$:

$a\Bbb E[ \theta_1(\mathbf X)] + \Bbb E[ \theta_2(\mathbf X)] - a \Bbb E[ \theta_2(\mathbf X)] 
=$

$= a  \theta +  \theta - a  \theta = \theta$.

Hence $\Bbb E[ \theta_3(\mathbf X)] = \theta$ and it is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$

Now I have the statistic $T(\mathbf X)= (\theta_1(\mathbf X), \theta_2(\mathbf X))$. I'm trying to show whether it's a complete statistic or not,
I tried to show that $T(\mathbf X)$ is a complete statistic using the following definition:

> Suppose that $T=T(\mathbf X)$ is a statistic taking values in  a set $\Theta$. Then $T$ is a complete statistic for $\theta$ if for any function $g: S \rightarrow \Bbb R$ :
>
> $\Bbb E_{\theta}[g(T)] = 0$ for all $\theta \in T \Rightarrow \Bbb >P_{\theta}[g(T)=0]=1$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$

So from this point i'm kind of stuck. Also, should I maybe use the fact that $\theta_3(\mathbf X)$ is unbiased? I have a feeling that constructing $g$ for $T(\mathbf X)$ based on $\theta_3(\mathbf X)$ being unbiased would help?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can't choose a function $g$. It says "for any function $g$".

Comment: well then how do I prove it "for any function $g$"?

Comment: A more approriate response than to ask the question again in a comment would be to correct the question.

Comment: @joriki ok, i will correct it

Comment: $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are different estimates or they coincide a.s.?

Comment: You may want to include the actual distributions and estimators, as is we cannot help.

Comment: they are distinct, yes

Comment: @P.Quinton Well, that is how the question is given, without anything specifying the distribution or estimators..

Comment: And then what is a question? If they are distinct, is $\mathbb P(\theta_1=\theta_2)=1?$

Comment: @NCh if they are distinct then this probability is not 1.

Comment: Last step. Is this statistics complete?

Comment: @NCh oh... yes, you're right :D. It's not. Thanks. Я был настолько зацыклен показать что оно равно одному, что забыл что если оно не равно, то тоже сойдёт за ответ :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists $g(x,y)=x-y$ such that $$\mathbb E[g(\theta_1(\mathbf X),\theta_2(\mathbf X))]=\mathbb E[\theta_1(\mathbf X)]-\mathbb E[ \theta_2(\mathbf X)]=0$$ for any $\theta$, and $$\mathbb P(g(\theta_1(\mathbf X),\theta_2(\mathbf X))=0)\neq 1$$ since the estimators do not coincide a.s., then $T(\mathbf X)=(\theta_1(\mathbf X),\theta_2(\mathbf X))$ is not complete by definition.

Comment: what does "a.s" mean?

Comment: *almost sure*, or *with probability $1$*.

Comment: @joriki Great thanks for correcting misprints!